# JS getDate comparison doesn't work on certain dates

Tags: calendar, getdate

I'm working on a simple calendar on my website, and I'm trying to accomplish the following:

- Today's date should be on a dark background color (css class: nyt)
- Future days should appear on a lighter background color (css class: tuleva)
- Past days should appear with 0.5 opacity (css class: menny)

This is the javascript code that I'm using:

```
$(function() {
var date = new Date(),

currentDate = date.getFullYear() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + 

date.getDate();

$(".kalenteripv").each(function() {

var specifiedDate = $(this).data('date');
if (specifiedDate == currentDate) {
$(this).addClass('nyt');}  // this day 
else if (currentDate > specifiedDate) {
$(this).addClass('menny');}  // past days 
else {$(this).addClass('tuleva');} // future days
});
});
```

Today (2017-12-2), for some reason the calendar is showing the dates 10-19 on 0.5 opacity, so the code is adding the "menny" or past dates' css class to those dates, which it obviously shouldn't do. I tried already to write the dates with two digits (e.g. 2017-12-**02**), but when I do that, the whole code stops working.

[Here's an image to clarify the problem with dates 10-19](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idbKY.jpg)

Any suggestions? It must be some kind of simple mistake that I'm making, but I really can't figure it out myself. I hope I explained the problem clear enough.

Here's the fiddle that shows the problem.

https://jsfiddle.net/vfy1bfnz/

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function pvmr() {

var today = new Date();

var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

if(dd<10) {
dd = '0'+dd
} 

if(mm<10) {
mm = '0'+mm
} 

today = yyyy + "-" + mm + "-" + dd;

$(".kalenteripv").each(function pvmr() {
var specifiedDate = $(this).data('date');




if (specifiedDate == today) {
  $(this).addClass('nyt');
} else if (today < specifiedDate) {
  $(this).addClass('tuleva');
} else if (today > specifiedDate) {
  $(this).addClass('menny');
}
});
});
```

Solved it! I thought I should leave the answer here in case someone needs the code some day.